# MySql query for finding second largest sal from each department

Tags: mysql

Given two tables emp(id,ename,sal,deptid) and dept(deptid,dname).

Find the dname, ename, and Second maximum salary from each department.
Can we solve it using joins

Means subquery with join

This was asked to me in interview and I am unable to fetch that department wise with dname.

```
SELECT d.name as department, max(sal) as second_maximum_salary, empID 
FROM emp e INNER JOIN dept d 
ON d.deptID = e.deptID 
where sal NOT IN (
SELECT MAX(sal) FROM emp GROUP BY deptID)
GROUP BY (e.deptID) 
ORDER BY second_maximum_salary DESC;
```

Comment: *"Can we solve it using joins"* : Yes. *"This was asked to me in interview and I am unable to fetch that department wise with dname."* Seems like you weren't ready then (but the stress of an interview can be rough for whiteboard questions). Go practice, you'll be ready for the next time

Comment: [Windows function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) is an option for you